# How to use a cython definition file (pxd) without making it an extension ?

Tags: cython, distutils

What is the simplest way to create a pxd definition file, which simply collects cdefs replicated over pyx files, without creating new extensions?

My case is the following: I would like to gather some extern cdefs in a pxd file (hp/src/common.pxd). I've also added some non-extern cdef, whose implementation is in common.pyx.

In another pyx file (hp/src/_lib.pyx), which I turn into an extension, I cimport some stuff from common.

In the setup.py file I create the following extension:

```
Extension('hp._lib', 
          ['hp/src/_lib.pyx'],
          language='c++'),
```

By doing so, no common.cpp file is created, so it looks like dependencies are not automatically handled. That's the first problem.

Then,  manually running 'cython --cplus common.pyx' correctly creates a common.cpp file in the directory hp/src, and if I add 'hp/src/common.cpp' to the list of the extension sources, the command python setup.py installs everything without complaint, but then, importing the module hp triggers an ImportError: No module named common... from _lib.cpp...
I'm stuck here. Any idea?

Comment: You can also try posting in [cython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cython-users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include material from another file using the `include` statement.

See the documentation here:

http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#the-include-statement

If you have external definitions in `common.pxd` and implementations in `commond.pyx` you will need to include them both. For example, in `_lib.pyx`:

```
include "common.pxd"
include "common.pyx"
```

The contents of these files will then be compiled into your `_lib` module as if they were textually included at that point. i.e. a `common.c` file will not be generated, but rather included with `_lib.c`.

The Cython compiler doesn't recognise changes to includes when deciding if the `.c` file for the module needs to be regenerated, so remember to delete this before you recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have much better luck if you structure your .pyx and .pxd files exactly as you would .py files.  This includes making an Extension for common.pyx in your `setup.py` file.  You may want to try using [cythonize](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-distutils) to handle the dependencies.